# how to stop a view from executing within a views hook

Tags: views, 8

I am using custom code with a views pre_execute and i want the view to return an empty set if certain conditions are met , or not to return the view at all. 
how can i do this ?  this is what i tried.

```
function mymodule_views_pre_execute(&$view) { 
   // if certain conditions are met i want this view to be empty or not come out at all
  if ($myconditions){
   $view = null;  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me, i unset all the results and the view disappeared

```
foreach ($view->result as $key => $value) {
    unset ($view->result[$key]); // delete a row

  }
```